# "Find Content" missing even though user has permission "Access the content overview page"

Tags: 7, navigation

The *Add content* menu item is available, but the *Find content* item is not visible, even though the account used to log in has the *Access the content overview page* permission and can access http://example.com/admin/content.

How can I make the *Find content* visible to that account?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem on a clean Drupal 7 installation — giving `Authenticated User` the "Access the content overview page" and "Use the administration toolbar" permissions causes the "Find content" link to appear in the Shortcut bar when that user is logged in.

Comment: Sounds like a menu problem and not a permission issue.  Try manually re-adding the menu item before completely re-installing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem: User's "Add Content" menu item is available, but "Find Content" is not.

Solution: Manually re-add the missing menu link.

**How to add an item to the admin short menu...**

Click Edit Shortcuts

[image: Click Edit Shortcuts]

Add a new shortcut

[image: Add a new shortcut]

Enter a Title, A URL and then Save

[image: Enter title, url and save]

You will now have the 'Find Content' shortcut in your admin shortcut bar as needed.

Side note:

If viewing admin/content you can also add the shortcut by simply clicking the + as noted in the graphic below:

[image: Example]

Comment: The question says `Content Editor has permission for "Access the content overview page"`.

Comment: Completely rewrote the answer to address the question.  There is no longer a reference to "Access the content overview page"

Comment: Expanded on how-to instructions as well.  OP indicated that they can already access the page in question, so permissions isn't the issue.  This sounds like a menu issue.  The above should re-add the 'find content' link as needed.

Comment: Thanks -- you pointed me in the right direction. I just had to enable Toolbar module (NOT Administration Menu Toolbar Style) and Shortcut module, and then Find Content appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Citricguy's answer is good, but it only adds a shortcut, when the op was actually asking about a menu item, which is what I wanted as well.

I've since realised that the default behaviour in Drupal 7 is for the admin (UID1) to get the "Management" menu as their black menu at the top, whereas all other users get the "Navigation" menu. You can however change this by granting users the permission "Use the administration pages and help". This is a valid solution because they will only see links to pages that they have permission to view/edit.

I personally think this should be the default behaviour (start off with everything, and then hide menu items that they don't have permissions for), but then I guess the current system allows you to manually hide certain menu items for non-admin users while keeping it for the admins. Certainly this area needs some thought as to the configuration options.

There's also the [Administration Menu Source](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu_source) module, which allows you to "use a different menu as the Administration Menu. Configurable per role".

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I had updated Drupal and modules to the latest versions (after not having upgraded for 2+ years) and the "Find Content" item was missing for one of our roles. Adding the "Use the administration pages and help" permission to that role fixed the problem. Thank you!